# Xirsys live-meeting api request structure example

Tags: webrtc, xirsys

Can i get an example of the structure for calling xirsys live meeting api through angular $http......url->https://service.xirsys.com/_r/live/meeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is format of making a ajax call to Xirsys live meeting api.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://service.xirsys.com/_r/live/meeting",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                username: "username:token",
                params: {
                    username: "me!",
                    path: "/DomainName/default/default",
                    meeting_id: meetingId
                }
            }
```

> Username,token are only provided to premium user by Xirsys.